# Can you render Jade as Html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Can you render jade as html?

```
.row
    html.
        #{content}
```

Where the content would be something like

```
<p> Hello World </p>
```

Thanks!

nb: doing it like that doesnt work :(

Comment: Use another view engine??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just replace `#{content}` with `!{content}`:

```
.row
    html.
        !{content}
```